# How to filter a datagridview when using data from datatable? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have created a textbox and want it to search through a database of customers by name. Most of the questions are using an external dataset but this is just using a table created in the program using a csv file.

Comment: Add relevant code.

Comment: Do you want it to search or do you want it to filter?  DataTables have filtering ability built in.  As is, this is too broad - please read [Ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: Easiest way IMO is to use a DateView created from your DataTable as the record source and use the Dataview's Filter.

Answer (score 4):

You could take advantage from `BindingSource`, to be used as DataSource of your DataGridView. That way, acting on the BindingSource Filter property, you could set any type of filters, based on you columns name.

Please check the following snippet:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable("Sample")
    dt.Columns.Add("Id")
    dt.Columns.Add("TimeStamp")

    For i As Int32 = 0 To 9999
        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {i, DateTime.Now})
    Next

    Dim bs As New BindingSource
    bs.DataSource = dt

    bs.Filter = "Id > 10 AND Id < 20"

    DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
```

As you can see, i've defined a DataTable with two columns, namely "Id" and "TimeStamp". Then, with a simple loop i've populated my DataTable with some random records, for Id = 0 to Id = 9999.

After that, we declare a BindingSource, specifying its DataSource is our DataTable. On the Bindinf Source, we could set any filter, using the Filter property, the columns names, and the common logical operators.

In my example, i've requested the filter to be on the only Id column, to visualize those record whose Id is between 11 and 19.

Then, we could use the BindingSource as our DataGridView DataSource.
And note that filters doesn't need to be apply before assigning the DataGridView DataSource: in fact, after the binding, each filter application will reflect immediately on the visualized rows.

Hope this helps

Comment: Could i use the '.filter' command for strings as well as integers?

Comment: Yes, supposing you have a string field named "Field", your Filter could be: bs.Filter = "Field = 'test'", or bs.Filter = "Field LIKE '%test%', if you need to filter by wildcard. You must watch out for injection, though, so it's better to escape the string which concur to the filter itself. Hope this helps